Why is this the variable not set?
Why is nonce undefined while debugging both in Chrome and Edge?


Setup:

Chrome(127.0.6533.101)
Edge(127.0.2651.98)
CSP header(s) NOT enabled.

Libraries:

"style-loader": "^2.0.0",
"url-loader": "^4.1.1",
"webpack": "^4.41.2",


both in Chrome and Edge - same pig with different lipstick - what about in an actually different browser?

@JaromandaX unfortunately I only have these two browsers to work with because of organizational restrictions.

You have __webpack_nonce__ set in the script tag, so it's not undefined, and it's a global variable available everywhere in your code.
However, you check the type of the options.attributes which you don't pass to insertStyleElement:

Therefore, {}.nonce === undefined
Looks like the easiest way to fix it is to remove the additional if (typeof attributes.nonce === "undefined") check, or to make sure you pass it when calling insertStyleElement.

The code block If (typeof attributes.nonce... is part of the following library that I don't have control of : https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader

You only specified insert and singleton options, but you should include attributes: { nonce: '...' } as well: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader?tab=readme-ov-file#attributes
This part of the code is never reached unless you have attributes.nonce in your config.
